# PHP Page Refresh not working inside loop

Tags: php

I want the page to be refreshed if the particular form is submitted after performing few tasks.
The page does it works but it does not refreshes, i don't know what exactly the problem is.

Here is the code :

**Update : I am using php action as self Is that affection the process**

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

  // form values here 

 </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
  //few operations
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 if($result)
 {
  header("Location: http://www.google.com");
 }
 else
 {
  //no operation
  }
  }
  ?>
```

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a new Location after you already have done some output like the form above, because then the headers for the document already have been generated. Headers can only be sent once and that should be at the very top of your PHP script, if you want to check for something.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `exit;` after the header.
If you skip the `exit;` or `die;` statements your script will continue to execute after the redirection header.

Comment: This is not an explanation for the above problem. It is false information

Comment: @hek2mgl if I'm wrong can you provide us with the correct explanation?

Comment: @SamuilBanti No. Even Chuck Norris can't answer this question. This is because the question lacks of sufficient information to reproduce the problem. This is a typical reason to close or flag the question. You should not answer such questions.

Comment: About `exit()` and `header()`. It is not required to exit the script immediately if you want to redirect the page. It doesn't matter if the script terminates after the `header()` call or not.

Comment: Now, where the question has been updated, @rinukkusu provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if a post request has been made is to check with and close with exit;

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST');
{
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. Actually i don't want to whether the form is done by post or not. But i need is to change the header location if particular action is done.